# "no such instruction error" when assembling an array declaration:

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, redhat

I have the following piece of x86 assembly code:

```
 1
 2        .text
 3
 4        .data
 5
 6        # define an array of 3 dwords
 7        array_word DW 1, 2, 3
 8
 9
10        .globl main
11
12main:
13 # nothing interesting ..
14
```

But when I compile this, I keep getting the following error:

```
$ gcc my_asm.s 
my_asm.s: Assembler messages:
my_asm.s:7: Error: no such instruction: `array_word DW 1,2,3'
```

This is the gcc I use:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Just use YASM or NASM if you're used to that syntax, or are following a tutorial that uses it.  Using gcc with `-masm=intel`, or a `.intel_syntax` directive, only switches instruction syntax, not assembler directives like `.globl main` vs. `global main`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - [`gas`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) (which is invoked by `gcc` for assembly files) uses a different syntax than other assemblers like `NASM`.

Use

```
array_word: .word 1, 2, 3
```

See also https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Word.html#Word

Note that the result of `.word` is target CPU specific - an alternative is [`.hword`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/hword.html#hword):

> 7.60 **.hword *expressions***
>
> This expects zero or more expressions, and emits a **16 bit number** for
>   each.
>
> This directive is a synonym for `.short`; depending on the target architecture, it may also be a synonym for `.word`.

By the way: you say `# define an array of 3 dwords` in your comment - but note that `DW` is `Define Word` which defines a 16 bit word. In `NASM`, you would use `DD` for 32 bit words.

Comment: If I want unsigned 32-bit, would it just be `.dword` ? (which didn't seem to work)

Comment: You can use `.long` - but that again depends on your architecture (which might not be relevant since you are usually assembling for some specific CPU) - at least, my `gcc` creates `.long   305419896` for `static const unsigned int someValue = 0x12345678;`

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Although, I should've been smarter and just looked at the assembly generated from `unsgined int[10] x;`! Best to learn from example.

Comment: Yes, exactly - if unsure just dump a few lines of `C` code to `gcc -S`